# Real time apps: Socket.io vs Pusherapp

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, django, real-time, websocket

What are the factors you would consider when choosing between [Socket.io](http://socket.io) and [Pusherapp](http://pusherapp.com)? Important considerations include: integration with existing systems like rails/django, ease of setup, ease of development.

Answer (score 9):

There are a few differentiating factors, these are:

1. Do you want to manage the scaling and hosting of your realtime infrastructure?
2. Do you want to receive data from your clients in realtime?
3. Do you want to be able to interact with the data between clients?

There's basically a few different use-cases for websockets, and at present no hosted solution can offer you two of those things. The current use cases I can think of are:

1. **Server** `--[ WebSocket ]->` Clients
2. **Server** `<-[ WebSocket ]--` Clients
3. **Server** `<-[ WebSocket ]->` Clients

Services like PusherApp target the first use-case, as it's fairly difficult to support the other two options with a hosted service. (Read: while it's difficult, it's just a bit impractical and doesn't give you the full benefits of using websockets.)

Comment: I should note that Pusher.com now supports the latter two options, with the release of the Pusher Pipe (alpha). The Pusher pipe enables the `server <-- pusher --> clients`. I should add as a disclaimer that I do now work at Pusher.